# Slide bar php with if and else condition value from dbase

Tags: php, slider

```
<label class="switch"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]"
 <?php if($row['status']=="active") {?> 
 <?php echo "checked";?> 
 <?php }?> 
 value="active"> 
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Please help me
I want to add else with condition unchecked and  value "inactive" for status in db which not equal active

I manage using 2 checkbox with value active and inactive but i want better looking with slidebar on/off

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use simple `if else`.. like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="status[]" <?php if($row['status']=="active") { echo 'checked value="active"'; }else{ echo 'value="inactive"';} >
```

Comment: you can also add a ternary operator as shorthand for this. like so `<?php echo ($row['status'] == 'active') ? 'checked value="active"' : 'value="inactive"'; >`

Comment: Thankyou  , i try both of them, well still getting error when post the value.when post the value end up with post inactive value ```if(isset($_POST['activate'])){
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $status = $_POST['status'];
 for($i=0;$i<count($id);$i++){$sql = "UPDATE apikey SET status='$status[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
  if ($connx->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "<h3><font color=#8BB2D9><center> update success!</center></font></h3>";
echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'keymgr.php';\",10);</script>";
  } else {
   echo $sql;
   echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
  }```

Comment: so you have another error because that's valide code :)

Comment: The code is valid to show value from database, active slide on inactive slide off but when i post the form i got trouble with post value from slider, i mention the isset post maybe i need revise on that

Comment: try to `var_dump($_POST);` for see every variable from POST.